# JavaFX traffic simulation transitions

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

im trying to build  traffic sim for college project.
Already implemented traffic light logic, dynamically controlling all the traffic lights etc...
Im stuck with adding vehicles as path transition nodes.
If i add alot of them with each one having its own boundsInParentProperty Change listener  which listens for:

-collision with other vehicles to keep them apart

-area in front of traffic light to be able to stop when red is on

then im ending up with alot of calculations that will make animations not ui friedly , app becomes unresponsive.

Im guessing transitions  needs to be part of main javafx ui thread, what about listeners?
any help on choosing correct approach is appreciated

Comment: How is the performance when you do not check for collision?

Comment: it runs smoothly with over 150 vehicles(represented by simple rectangles for now )

Answer (score 2):

The rules on threading are:

1. Any properties of Nodes that are part of the scene graph must be
   accessed by the FX Application Thread.
2. Avoid doing any unnecessary calculations on the FX Application Thread.

Obviously, you're in the case where this gets tricky to manage, because the lengthy calculations involve the very properties that have to be accessed on the FX Application Thread.

The javafx.concurrent package and the javafx.animation package have a number of facilities to ease thread management. Specifically, there are a number of callbacks defined which area executed on the FX Application Thread.

Nodes modify their properties, and consequently execute any change listener's methods on the FX Application Thread. Transitions update the state of the properties they manipulate on the FX Application Thread, and do the same with callbacks such as `setOnFinished(...)`. In the javafx.concurrent API, the `Task` class has a `call(...)` method which is intended to be executed on a background thread, and there are various callback methods (`updateMessage(...)`, `updateProgress(...)`), as well as some handlers: `setOnSucceeded(...)` etc, that are all executed on the FX Application Thread.

For a simulation like this, I would recommend looking at the [AnimationTimer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html). This has a `handle()` method for you to implement, which is invoked once for every render frame. It receives a `long` argument which is a timestamp in nanoseconds. The target frame rate for JavaFX is (currently) 60fps, so you should aim for code that executes reasonably quickly in here, else you will slow the frame rate, but you can actually accomplish quite a lot in 16ms.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/james-d/8327842) is an example using this technique. This just simulates lots of balls bouncing around in a box, but it'll give you an idea. I also had a version kicking around somewhere in which each ball implemented it's own `AnimationTimer` to check for wall collisions, and then there was another AnimationTimer which checked ball-ball collisions; the performance was pretty much identical (which is not a surprise). I used the "AnimationFrame per object" approach in an unfinished Space Invaders simulation as well, and it worked pretty well.

Comment: This is result so far. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ccEN7PK2-F8 In real time it runs smoothly.Used animation timer as loop as suggested.Would appreciate if you can find example of each ball having its own animation timer. Thanks